# RemoveAll on set of records before insert doesn't remove matching records in set of existing records

Tags: apex, set

I've run into an issue comparing sets of records to insert vs sets of records that already exist as the set of existing records contains a record ID and therefore the `removeAll` method doesnt see a match

I've got these two sets in my code, both of which only have one element in my test.  The elements have the same values, except the existing record has an Id.

`cgmembers:` a set of all existing collaborationgroupmember records

```
{CollaborationGroupMember:{CollaborationGroupId=0F9L00000005hpDKAQ, Id=0FBL0000000gDtWOAU, MemberId=00540000001CkxPAAS}}
```

`cgUsersToInsertSet:` set of records I want to insert.  This set also has one element (without an Id, as they are not inserted yet)

```
{CollaborationGroupMember:{MemberId=00540000001CkxPAAS, CollaborationGroupId=0F9L00000005hpDKAQ}}
```

I need to remove the existing collaborationGroupMembers from the set of records to insert before inserting them, else I get a duplicate record error.  Using two sets and RemoveAll seemed like a good approach...until it didnt work.

So how can I do this efficiently?

Is there a way to populate the set of existing records without the ID field?
Or if not whats the most efficient way to do the comparison?

Below is a snippet of the code that shows how I'm populating the cgmembers set (the existing collaborationGroupMembers, which has the ID field)

```
     Map<String, CollaborationGroup> chatterGroups = new Map<String, CollaborationGroup>();
           FOR (CollaborationGroup chatterGroup : 
           [SELECT Name, (SELECT CollaborationGroupId, MemberId FROM GroupMembers) FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Name IN :chatterGroupNames]) 
           chatterGroups.put(chatterGroup.Name, chatterGroup);


            FOR (PermissionSet_Map__c psmap : psmaps){

                string cg = psmap.collaborationgroup__c;

                //cgx = current chatter group in loop
                CollaborationGroup cgx = ChatterGroups.get(cg);

                cgmembers.addAll(cgx.GroupMembers)
```

Thank you!

**EDIT - using a FOR loop to create sObject without ID field**

so far the best I've been able to do is to use a FOR loop to create a collaborationGroupMember sObject without the ID field.  Seems redundant, hopefully there is a better way.

```
set <collaborationGroupMember> cgmembersNoId = new set <collaborationGroupMember>();
                FOR (collaborationGroupMember cgm : cgmembers){
                   collaborationGroupMember cgmx = new collaborationGroupMember();
                    cgmx.MemberId = cgm.MemberId;
                    cgmx.CollaborationGroupId = cgm.CollaborationGroupId;
                    cgMembersNoId.add(cgmx);
                }
```

Comment: Why can't you use upsert instead of insert?

Comment: interesting idea!  looks like upsert is not supported on collaborationgroupmember Supported Calls
create(), delete(), describeSObjects(), describeLayout(), query(), retrieve(), update() - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroupmember.htm

Comment: upsert is combination of insert and update. If a salesforce id or external id is present in database that records is updated, else inserted. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_section.htm#apex_dml_upsert

Comment: will test it out but from what i've seen if upsert is allowed on the object, its listed as a supported operation in the documentation, ie for account: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm  - Supported Calls
create(), delete(), describeLayout(), describeSObjects(), getDeleted(), getUpdated(), merge(), query(), retrieve(), search(), undelete(), update(), upsert()

Comment: Am able to use upsert on list of CollaborationGroupMember with one record with id and another without id.

Comment: Thanks for testing it!  I will give it a shot and see how it works.  It would use a lot of unnecessary dml, as most of the members will already exist, so would still be worth some addl overhead to remove the dupes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36670/discussion-between-vigneshwaran-g-and-gorav).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found is to run the list of `collaborationgroupmembers` through a FOR loop to create a new list that does not contain the Id field, and use that in the removeAll method.

```
set <collaborationGroupMember> cgmembersNoId = new set <collaborationGroupMember>();
                FOR (collaborationGroupMember cgm : cgmembers){
                   collaborationGroupMember cgmx = new collaborationGroupMember();
                    cgmx.MemberId = cgm.MemberId;
                    cgmx.CollaborationGroupId = cgm.CollaborationGroupId;
                    cgMembersNoId.add(cgmx);
                }
```